# Codeigniter delete record where some select query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In codeigniter I want to delete record from a table. But at the same time I want to remove a record from another table which having foreign key to that record.
Is there any possible way to do this using codeigniter?

1st delete query

```
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->delete('category_info');
```

1st table

id | description | image

2nd table

id   |   category_id    |    parent_category

Comment: You don't need PHP/codeigniter for this, just use [mysql triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) after deletion.

Comment: But the framework I'm using is codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having PHP doing the heavy work, you can do this straight from MYSQL with a trigger. This will trigger after a deletion.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_trigger_tbl_2 AFTER DELETE ON category_info
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM tbl_2
    WHERE tbl_2.id = old.id; 
-- Or category_id, not clear in your question.
END
```